# Best practice: Asp.net WebApp requires user authentication - what to do during development to avoid logging on again and again?

Tags: asp.net

When I develop an ASP.Net webapp, it almost always requires some kind of authentication - ie. the user must log in for stuff to work.

But when I am developing it, I don't want to have to log in every time I make a change to some code.

So right now for instance, I have a codeblock in my login.aspx, that automatically authenticates me as a certain userId - and redirects me back to the requested page.

I have a few other ideas that are more elegant for handling development vs. live - but I would like to hear how you handle the same situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could actually tackle the problem completely differently: Use [unit tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) tests to exercise small bits of your code. As unit tests run automatically (once started), you will save the time for logging in & navigating to the right page.

You will of course still have to do some end-to-end testing by logging in the regular way, but in my experience, if your unit tests all succeed, the probability of errors in the end-to-end test is much lower, hence much less restarts.

I've used this extensively when developing applications where triggering the functionality under development required a lot of clicking, and found it a great timesaver.

The suggestions in the other posts will of course still be helpful for the cases where you still need to run the app the normal way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm always lazy and just write some code to test for localhost.

Answer (score 1):

You could alter your cookie implementation based on a debug build versus a production build. Keep your cookies persistent and you should be ok.

Comment: That is, keep you cookies persistent for local debug builds and you shouldn't have to keep logging in.

Answer (score 0):

I use Firefox for my client but have the debugger start up IE.  I login with Firefox and when I start/stop the debugger, my Firefox client stays logged in.   Only rarely do I have to actually login again -- typically when I've left it long enough that the session expires.  I find that I can tolerate it and I don't introduce any code that may, in turn, introduce security problems to handle login differently in DEV.

Answer (score 0):

A technique I've sometimes used is to define a list of development machine names in a config file setting. The machine name is then compared at runtime to the list. If its in the list, then we can execute some special code to make development & debugging a little less tedious for everyone.